# How to bind to a Elements data- attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have a data attribute like:

```
<a href="stuff" data-open-dialog="location-XXXX">click</a>

<a href="stuff" data-open-dialog="location-YYYY">click</a>
```

How can I bind to data-open-dialog, and obtain value, either XXXX or YYYY?

I know how to bind to a specific value, like:

```
a[data-open-dialog="location-XXXX"]
```

but how can I make the value dynamic and then obtain the value on click?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>What you are doing is not really "bind"-ing. You just want to retrieve its value, or so I think.</s>

Try something like this:

```
$('a[data-open-dialog]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var location = $(this).data('open-dialog');

    ...
});
```

`location` will then hold *location-XXXX* or *location-YYYY*. It should be a simple matter for you to strip the "location-" part.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean that you want to select any element that has an attribute, and then get the value of that attribute on the click event.  If so, use the has-attribute selector:

```
$('a[data-open-dialog]').click(function() {
    var location = $(this).data('open-dialog');
});
```

If you just want the `XXX` part, you should do `.substr(9)` to remove the first 9 characters of the string.

See the jQuery manual:

- [has attribute selector (`[attribute]`)](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector)
- [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data_contains = function(obj, val) {
    console.log(obj, val);
    if ($(obj).data('open-dialog') != undefined) {
        if ($(obj).data('open-dialog') == val) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$('a').filter(function() {
    return data_contains(this, "location-XXXX");
}).click(function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
    return false;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/H75JD/3/